# What is wrong with this sub query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

```
select lunch_date
from l_lunches
where employee_id = (select employee_id
from l_employees
where hire_date <  #1/1/2000#;)
```

Getting an error statement stating " at most one record can be returned by this subquery"

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your subquery (select employee_id from l_employees where hire_date <  #1/1/2000#; ) is returning more than one record. Consider using JOIN statement.

Comment: If your subquery returns more than a single value you should use 'IN' instead of '='.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select lunch_date
from l_lunches
where employee_id IN (select employee_id
from l_employees
where hire_date <  #1/1/2000#;)
```

Comment: Thank you @sean bartram that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

This portion of query should return at most only one value for it to work.

```
select employee_id
from l_employees
where hire_date <  #1/1/2000
```

Can you post the problem description or try using Cross Apply etc.

Comment: Thank you the first person has helped me i appreciate you and your time.

Answer (score 0):

your sub query must be returning more than one record , you can try inner join if you want to list all employees after that hiredate

```
 select lunch_date
   from l_lunches
  inner join l_employees on l_lunches.employee_id = l_employees.employee_id
 where l_employees.hire_date <  #1/1/2000#
```

Comment: Thank you the first answer works out for me but i appreciate your time. I can see where yours makes sense also.